# Wordpress Hide or Disable Comment Box Conditionally With PHP

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to allow user only one comment in a post.

I check/validate my user comments with `preprocess_comment` filter hook. And stop for multiple comments.

But I can not hide the comment form box after user make the comment.
when a user comment in a post then the comment box will disable/hide from the page.

Help please

Comment: Please write more information like: what is the theme (your custom one?). Also post some code examples, otherwise no one would be able to help you here.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create your custom `comment.php` template of course comment form also in your theme.
Check this link
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/partial-and-miscellaneous-template-files/comment-template/

End of the page:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/partial-and-miscellaneous-template-files/comment-template/#the-end

```
<?php
    if( YOUR_CONDITION_FUNCTION_OR_LOGIC() ){
        comment_form();
    }
?>
```

Hope it helps you.